# Filter rows containing certain values in the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I want to filter out rows contains specific values through out multiple columns in data frame.

E.g

```
    code tag number floor  note
1   1111  *   **     34     no 
2   2323  7   899     7     no
3   3677  #   900    11     no
4   9897  10  134    *      no
5    #    #   566    11     no
6   3677  55  908    11     no
```

I want to filter out all rows contains #, *, ** in columns code, tag, number, floor.

What I want to get is

```
    code tag number floor  note
1   1111  *   **     34     no 
3   3677  #   900    11     no
4   9897  10  134    *      no
5    #    #   566    11     no
```

I was trying to use isin method in data frame, but it does work with one column, but does not work in multiple columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
Assuming no other pre-existing `pir`

```
df[df.replace(['#', '*', '**'], 'pir').eq('pir').any(1)]

   code tag number floor note
1  1111   *     **    34   no
3  3677   #    900    11   no
4  9897  10    134     *   no
5     #   #    566    11   no
```

---

**Option 2**
Obnoxious `numpy` broadcasting.  Fast at first but scales quadratically

```
df[(df.values[None, :] == np.array(['*', '**', '#'])[:, None, None]).any(0).any(1)]

   code tag number floor note
1  1111   *     **    34   no
3  3677   #    900    11   no
4  9897  10    134     *   no
5     #   #    566    11   no
```

---

**Option 3**
Less obnoxious `np.in1d`

```
df[np.in1d(df.values, ['*', '**', '#']).reshape(df.shape).any(1)]

   code tag number floor note
1  1111   *     **    34   no
3  3677   #    900    11   no
4  9897  10    134     *   no
5     #   #    566    11   no
```

---

**Option 4**
Over the top with `map`

```
df[list(
    map(bool,
        map({'*', '**', '#'}.intersection,
            map(set,
                zip(*(df[c].values.tolist() for c in df)))))
)]

   code tag number floor note
1  1111   *     **    34   no
3  3677   #    900    11   no
4  9897  10    134     *   no
5     #   #    566    11   no
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `apply`, `isin`, and `any` with boolean indexing:

```
list = ['#','*','**']
cols = ['code','tag','number','floor']
df[df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.isin(list).any(), axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   code tag number floor note
1  1111   *     **    34   no
3  3677   #    900    11   no
4  9897  10    134     *   no
5     #   #    566    11   no
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `df.applymap`:

```
s = {'*', '**', '#'}
df[df.applymap(lambda x: x in s).max(1)]

   code tag number floor note
1  1111   *     **    34   no
3  3677   #    900    11   no
4  9897  10    134     *   no
5     #   #    566    11   no
```

---

piR [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947302/python-pandas-filter-rows-with-certain-values-in-multiple-columns/45947460?noredirect=1#comment78853504_45947460) a crazy (but it works!) alternative:

```
df[df.apply(set, 1) & {'*', '**', '#'}]

   code tag number floor note
1  1111   *     **    34   no
3  3677   #    900    11   no
4  9897  10    134     *   no
5     #   #    566    11   no
```

Comment: @piRSquared Reeling from the fact that it works. Added it as an answer if you're okay with that?